# In R: sort the maximum dissimilarity between rows in a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix, which includes 100 rows and 10 columns, here I want to compare the diversity between rows and sort them. And then, I want to select the 10 maximum dissimilarity rows from it, Which method can I use?

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(runif(100 * 10), nrow = 100, ncol = 10)
```

My initial method is to calculate the similarity (e.g. saying tanimoto coefficient or others: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index ) between two rows, and dissimilairty = 1 - similarity, and then compare the dissimilarty values. At last I will sort all dissimilarity value, and select the 10 maximum dissimilarity values. But it seems that the result is a 100 * 100 matrix, maybe need efficient method to such calculation if there are a large number of rows. However, this is just my thought, maybe not right, so I need help.

[update] 
After looking for some literatures. I find the one definition for the maximum dissimilarity method.

Maximum dissimilarity method: It begins by randomly choosing a data record as the first cluster center. The record maximally distant from the first point is selected as the next cluster center. The record maximally distant from both current points is selected after that . The process repeats itself until there is a sufficient number of cluster centers.

Here in my question, the sufficient number should be 10.

Thanks.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? S.O. as a site expects you to usually show what you have done and where you've hit a wall before asking a question.

Comment: @thelatemail, thank you. I have edit my question, but maybe it is still vague to depict my question. Need people help.

Comment: Take a simple example with 3 rows, you will get a similarity measure for each combination, e.g. `r1/r2` `r1/r3` `r2/r3`, so you're only going to be able to get the 10 most dissimilar pairs of rows, not 10 rows.

Comment: @thelatemail. Thank you. You are right. But as metasoarous suggested that is a good way to measure the dissimilarity between rows and the center. I will further think about my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the Jacard Index is not right for you. From the wikipedia page

> The Jaccard coefficient measures similarity between finite sample sets...

Your matrix has samples of floats, so you have a different problem (note that the Index in question is defined in terms of intersections; that should be a red flag right there :-).

So, you have to decide what you mean by dissimilarity. One natural interpretation would be to say row A is more dissimilar from the data set than row B if it has a greater Euclidean distance to the center of mass of the data set. You can think of the center of mass of the data set as the vector you get by taking the mean of each of the colums and putting them together (`apply(mat, 2, mean)`).

With this, you can take the distance of each row to that central vector, and then get an ordering on those distances. From that you can work back to the rows you desire from the original matrix.

All together:

```
center <- apply(mat, 2, mean)
# not quite the distances, actually, but their squares. That will work fine for us though, since the order
# will still be the same
dists <- apply(mat, 1, function(row) sum((row - center) ** 2))
# this gives us the row indices in order of least to greaest dissimiliarity
dist.order <- order(dists)
# Now we just grab the 10 most dissimilar of those
most.dissimilar.ids <- dist.order[91:100]
# and use them to get the corresponding rows of the matrix
most.dissimilar <- mat[most.dissimilar.ids,]
```

If I was actually writing this, I probably would have compressed the last three lines as `most.dissimilar <- mat[order(dists)[91:100],]`, but hopefully having it broken up like this makes it a little easier to see what's going on.

Of course, if distance from the center of mass doesn't make sense as the best way of thinking of "dissimilarity" in your context, then you'll have to amend with something that does.

Comment: thanks you. your answer gives me a reasonable method.Yes, the distance from the center is a good method. Maybe a little typo in your last code is that the comma is missing and add it as:
`most.dissimilar <- mat[most.dissimilar.ids, ]`   Thanks again for your explanation.